# how to find the gradient of the tangents to the curves at the given points

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the gradient of the tangents to the curve $$y= \frac{x^2 + 1}{x + 2}$$ at the given points $(2,5/4)$.

I'm not sure how to approach this question because my lecturer has never done anything like this in class. I was wondering if I must use the quotient rule, honestly not sure. Please show me the solution along with explanation so I can understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**:

- Calculate $f'(x)$ using, indeed, the quotient rule.

> $$f'(x)=\dfrac{(2x)(x+2)-(x^2+1)}{(x+2)^2}=\dfrac{x^2+4x-1}{(x+2)^2}$$

- Find the gradients by substituting $x=2$ and $x=\frac54$.

> Ex.: for $x=2$, we have $f'(2)=\dfrac{2^2+4\cdot2-1}{(2+2)^2}=\dfrac{11}{16}$.